# Is there a way to detect that Python is running a test?

Tags: python, testing

I want to suppress certain warning messages when Python is running in a test context.

Is there any way to detect this globally in Python?

Comment: It probably depends on how you run tests, but the simplest and most universal thing to do would probably be to set a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't really detect whether or not you're in a test context, or you'd do it with a lot of unnecessary processing. For example: having a state variable in the testing package that you set up when you're running your tests. But then you would include that module (or variable) in all of your modules, which would be far from being elegant. *Globals are evil*.

The best way to implement filtering output based on the execution context is to use the `logging` module and make all unnecessary warning messages at a low level (like `DEBUG`) and ignore them when you run your tests.

Another option would be to add a level for all of the messages you explicitly ignore when running the tests.

Comment: Ah, in my case the answer is to turn off the `WARN` level or all logging altogether during tests.

Comment: but if you use the python `testing` module or `nose` module, it shall handle very nicely stdout/stderr, as well as separating it from all logging, and return a nice view of both output! And then, you could have all the outputs in the worst verbosity you can find *when and only when* a test fails. Aren't you using them?